# What's wrong with this org-mode template?

Tags: emacs, elisp, text-editor, org-mode

I can't get the prompt for entering tags to work. I've put the code in my .emacs file along with  %^g which should call the prompt but that isn't working.

This is in my .emacs file.

```
 (setq org-capture-templates
  '(("t" "Todo" entry (file+headline "~/.emacs.d/gtd.org" "Tasks")
         "* TODO %?\n  %i\n  %a")
    ("j" "Journal" entry (file+datetree "~/.emacs.d/journal.org")
         "* %?%^g \nEntered on %U\n  %i\n")))
```

When I call the journal code I get no prompt and the output below

```
* %? 
Entered on [2011-04-20 Wed 06:59]
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for having letting me discover this mode I didn't know anything about. Now, I'm scared.

Answer (score 1):

I'm (almost) sorry to say that it works for me.  Maybe you have an old version of Org Mode?  I am running 7.5.

You can find the version by typing

`M-x org-version`

Additionally, you may want a space between the %? and the %^g for convenience.  Good luck on making it work.